# How reduce uboot source to specific board?

Tags: makefile, mips, u-boot

I want to get minimal U boot image for specific board. How could I print all source need for this?

I used "make -n" but it was not a source list.

Comment: "*I want to get minimal U boot image ...*" -- Then you'll have to manually configure U-Boot for a minimal set of features/capabilities and only build the drivers necessary to boot. "*How could I print all source need for this?*" -- Work on the configuration and build first, then get the **.c** files for the **.o** files built?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that you don't reduce the source code. To make the resulting binary smaller, modify the config to disable features you don't need.  Assuming this is a current release, "make menuconfig" or similar, just like the linux kernel, and disable things.